# awk math: check result before printing

Tags: awk

My input is:

```
cat input  
   1  
   4  
  -2
```

I want to subtract some value (e.g., `2`) from column 1. If result is `> 0` print it or else print `0`. In other words, I don't want any negative numbers.

My try is:

```
 awk '{NUMBER=$1-2} if (NUMBER > 0) print NUMBER; else print 0'
```

But I am probably making some syntax mistake.

Wanted ouput is:

```
0
2
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be an option:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1-2>0?$1-2:0; print $1}' file
0
2
0
```

`$1=$1-2>0?$1-2:0` is a ternary operator and is read like this:

```
Set $1 to:

    if ($1-2 > 0)
         ==> $1-2
    else ==> 0
```

and then it is printed out `print $1`.

Answer (score 2):

With this:

```
awk '{NUMBER=$1-2} if (NUMBER > 0) print NUMBER; else print 0'
```

you're putting the `if...` statement in the condition part of the awk body instead of the action part because it's not enclosed in curly brackets. This is the correct syntax for what you wrote:

```
awk '{NUMBER=$1-2; if (NUMBER > 0) print NUMBER; else print 0}'
```

but in reality I'd write it as:

```
awk '{NUMBER=$1-2; print (NUMBER > 0 ? NUMBER : 0)}'
```